# Don't understand this Expected Value notation (E*)

Tags: expected-value

I was shown this problem and I don't recognize the E* notation. Clearly (?) it's different from E for expectation, but related.

Does anyone know this and/or point me to a suitable reference?

[image: the question]

Comment: Where did this question came from?

Comment: The only use I can think of for the notation $E^*$ is for outer expectation but it does not seem to be the case here

Comment: Can you please include the source for this? It would provide further context

Answer (score 2):

I appears that the expected value symbol with an asterisk indicates conditional expectation... It's the first time I see something like this, but it is the only queue I can see...

Comment: that sounds right - i missed that...